# Issue while open some of the excel file while export to excel function in c# web application

Tags: c#, excel, export-to-excel

i have an web application, and there is an export to excel function. While I try to open some of the excel file downloaded from this export to excel function, it shows the error while opening them as,

> We found a problem with some content in ---.xlsx. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this
>   workbook, click yes.

Can any one kindly help me to solve this?

Best regards.

Comment: please show the export code.

Comment: I think there is no error in the export code. Because for only some of the excel document it shows the error. Is there any chances to get error due to changes in the data types of the displayed column?

Comment: I think so. For example, I had a case like this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29970814/1271037. this nout your case but example. see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/9864552/1271037 It might be your case. but without example (or a problematic xlsx to examine) its hard to help

Comment: "export to excel function" - is this from any third party control code ? (OR) is this something you have written ? Since you say, it works for some files, it is likely to be some data is causing this problem.

Comment: you should post your code to show us what technique are you using. At least a piece of code that reproduce your issue. There are plenty of options for exporting and your question have too many possible solutions.